# Function missing but file including it is loaded? (Uncaught ReferenceError: flashembed is not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-tools

[jQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/toolbox/flashembed.html) is a stand-alone library that offers a flashembed() function; it does not require jQuery.  But with or without jQuery I am seeing error `Uncaught ReferenceError: flashembed is not defined`

Page html from [here](http://www.itsneworleans.dreamhosters.com/test.html)  and a [JSFiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/bpsUL/1/).

```
<div class="ads-box" id="ad1">
<script>flashembed("ad1", "/g/shows/sidebar/72940064_ad_swf.swf");</script>
</div>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

The SWF is not 404 
http://www.itsneworleans.dreamhosters.com/g/shows/sidebar/72940064_ad_swf.swf

And the CDN file has the flashembed function and resources tab shows it loaded.
http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js

[image]

What is my next step in debugging this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load jQuery Tools, and jQuery **before** you call `flashembed`

Comment: Thank you.  But that's only partially correct. jQuery Tools is a stand-alone and despite name does not require jQuery.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh That is good to know. I guess it is a misnomer then :)